# I can't call Controller Action via Ajax Post

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I have some issue about local and published web project differences. I have a .net core mvc project and  I tried to save physically save file in controller.  I get file from file selector then pass my FileModel.
But in locally everthing is fine, I could access controller than save file, but After published on server, than I tried to upload file I coudldnt access to controllers method.

My ajax post code here: (FileUpdateIndex.cshtml)

```
 if (form != null)
            {
                $.ajax({
                    url:"SavePhysicalPath",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: form,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    success: function (result){console.log("success!");}
                    error: function (result){console.log("error!");}
             }
```

FileUpdateController.cs

```
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult SavePhysicalPath(FileModel model)
        {
...
...
some code
...
        }
```

İn local everything good, I get console log success! ,
but in published: **(my site www url)/MyProject/FileUpdate/SavePhysicalPath 404 Not Found.**

how can I solve this?

Comment: Hi @hkyaaa,404 means the request url is not correct,please check the url here:`url:"SavePhysicalPath",`.

Comment: Hi @Rena , this url locally worked and posted , but in my website why couldnt access?

Comment: Hi @hkyaaa you user full url instead of just action name. Possibly you using url rewriting so can't found your action. you should use `url:"www.yoursite.com/FileUpdate/SavePhysicalPath"`

Comment: Or just `url: '/FileUpdate/SavePhysicalPath'`

Comment: unfortunately coulnt work still 404

Comment: @josibu any suggestion ?

Comment: Can you please try `url:'@Url.Action("SavePhysicalPath","FileUpdate")'`

Comment: Maybe the code inside the `SavePhysicalPath` function returns `NotFound()` or equivalent somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your website are located at MyProject you have to add MyProject name to your ajax url:

```
 url:"/MyProject/FileUpdate/SavePhysicalPath",
```

or  you can create a helper function:

```
function getUrl(controllerAction) {
        var ca = controllerAction.split('/');
        var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split('/');

if (pathArray[1].toLowerCase() != ca[1].toLowerCase()) return "/" + pathArray[1] + controllerAction;
        return controllerAction;
    }
```

in this case you can use it for your ajax local or production url like:

```
   url:getUrl("/FileUpdate/SavePhysicalPath"),
```

This function will be working properly only if you have one level of your subfolders. If you have two or more levels you will have to correct it.